Oracle Forms 12c - Duplicate a trigger in multiple forms
In Oracle Forms 12C, using Forms Builder, Forms API Master, Forms Migration or any other 3rd party tool - Is there a way to batch create/replace the same form-level trigger on 300+ forms without opening and editing each form individually in Form Builder?
Example: I have a new form-level trigger. In some forms, the trigger exists but needs to be replaced, and in some forms, the trigger doesn’t exist at all. Every form will have an identical copy of the trigger. Is there a way to “batch-enter” the same trigger to 300+ forms? (Can’t use a library or database procedure as there are references to form objects in the trigger.) I am trying to update/add the trigger to all 300+ forms without opening each one in Form Builder.
I looked through Forms API Master and the Oracle 12C Form Builder API. They allow one to write a C++ script to perform many complex Forms functions using the Forms API Master APIs and a command-line interface but I am a PLSQL guy, and know very little about C++ so doing so is beyond my capability. I had hoped someone else may have written one but if they have, they aren’t talking about it online.
I had considered converting all my FMBs to text files (FMTs) and using a text search/replace function, then reconvert all back to FMBs but that would be almost as much work.
